# How to measure the time that has passed between two events in python?

Tags: python, api, classification

I need some help with this situation (btw I'm new in python and it's my first question): I'm making automatic indicators using APIs. I classify events in differents categories, something like

```
def process():
df=pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(x.xlsx))

speed= df['speed']
status= []

for sp in speed:
    if sp <= 5:
        status.append('stopped')
    elif speed <= 40 and speed > 5:
            status.append('slow movement')
    elif speed <= 90 and speed > 40:
        status.append('normal movement')
```

The fact is that I make a new consult to the API once per hour, so that information it's changing. What I need to do it's to measure the time that has passed between two consult. In other words, if in some moment of time one value is equal to 'stopped', I want to know how much time that value has the same classification. I tried something like:

```
data['timeNow'] = time.time()

for stat in data['status']:
if stat == 'stopped':
    data['endTime'] = time.time()
    data['timePassed'] = data['endTime'] - data['timeNow']
    
data['cumulatedTime'] = data['timePassed']
```

but the problem with this is that it's static.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
def print_hello():
    def time_taken():
        print("Hello world")
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - starting))

    timer = threading.Timer(10, time_taken)
    timer.start()
    starting = time.time()
```

**Note:** You need to `import threading`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).